# SSH Sometimes works, sometime doesn't - local network

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I've started having the strangest of issues where when I attempt to SSH into the server sitting next to me, it refuses to connect. If I keep trying eventually it will connect.

```
~ $ ssh 192.168.0.10
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 22: Connection refused
~ $ ssh 192.168.0.10
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 22: Connection refused
~ $ ssh 192.168.0.10
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 22: Connection refused
~ $ ssh 192.168.0.10
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.10 port 22: Connection refused
~ $ ssh 192.168.0.10
chris@192.168.0.10's password: <--- Connected here
```

My first thought was this is some kind of DHCP induced IP conflict on my network, but after carefully checking that isn't the case.

The strange thing is everything is random about it, sometimes it works straight away, others it can take over 100 attempts. Sometimes on my laptop (via WiFi) it works first time and fails other times, vs my wired Desktop which used to always work but is now starting to show the same behavior.

Has anyone experienced this before? What logs should I be looking at on my server to help work out what is causing this strange behavior?

The server is running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Don't rule out  an IP conflict yet.  The next time it happens, check your arp  cache with `sudo  arp -an`  to ensure the MAC address for 192.168.0.10 actually matches the server's MAC.  If it doesn't, you might have a rogue device intermittently using 192.168.0.10

Answer (score 2):

In case this is helping you, I had a similar problems.

AFter ruling out `fail2ban` and `sshd_config` I found out that I used `ufw` with a `LIMIT` rule to the ssh port. I blanky allowed SSH and now it works. Issue was with too many connections.

Answer (score 1):

Does this 'server' have a public facing SSH port?

You could be results of someone trying to brute force logins to your server if you have the default `MaxStartups` settings the server will only allow a limited number of incoming connection attempts at any given point in time, and will reject the rest.

The logs you would see in this case would be tons of authentication failures in `/var/log/auth.log`.

You could also be getting rejected from some other intrusion prevention system perhaps implemented with netfilter or something else.

Assuming this is a result of the MaxStartups or some other intrusion prevention system, you should generally not make SSH public facing, or if it is public facing limit the incoming addresses to trusted subset or require a VPN or something.

Putting ssh on a non-standard port can help cut down probing and brute forcing from the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll take a look at those logs but I don't have 22 exposed to the outside world. Edit: Yeah looking at those logs there isn't anything in them out of the ordinary :(